# PHP preg_match returns null. Why?

Tags: wordpress, preg-match

The following preg_match call returns null within a Wordpress code:

```
preg_match('/(<div class="title-primary">)([^<]*)(<\/div>)/', $content, &$matches)
```

Even if the input contains: `<div class="title-primary"> bla-bla </div>`.

There are no PHP errors.

This works well when tested with online tools:

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <div class="title-primary">
                     bla-bla            </div>
    [1] => <div class="title-primary">
    [2] =>
                     bla-bla
    [3] => </div>
)
```

Any idea what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This indeed works well when testing with online tools or my own environment. Submitted at http://phptester.net/

```
<?php
$content = '<div class="title-primary"> bla-bla </div>';

preg_match('/(<div class="title-primary">)([^<]*)(<\/div>)/', $content, &$matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Result:

```
Array ( [0] =>
bla-bla
[1] =>
[2] => bla-bla [3] =>
)
```

Which means that it must be something else in your code that prevents this from running properly. First thing that I would look at would be why you are using pass-by-reference operator with $matches - is there a chance that $matches gets over-written somewhere in between the preg_match and the point at which you are debugging the code?

Comment: Thanks for the quick *correct* reply.
The problem is that strlen($content) is 0 (zero)!
But otherwise - all is functioning well... 
Its a nasty wordpress&my-code - issue.